# Disabling Message History spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to get message history enabled based on environments, is there a way to turn ON/OFF MessageHistory based on a property value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring profiles (and the `spring.profiles.active` property) to conditionally include beans - so put the message history tag in a profile.

**EDIT**

```
<beans ...

    ...

    <beans profile="enableHistory>
        <int:message-history ... />
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Comment: What if I have it declared the xml way?<int:message-history tracked-components="*Gateway, sample*, foo"/>